# Code analysis in Visual Studio 2012 vs. FxCop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, fxcop

I am new to the code analysis. Here I don’t know the difference and the usages between the code analysis tool in Visual Studio 2012 and the [FxCop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) tool.

What are some details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FxCop / Code Analysis with VS2010 Ultimate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918678/fxcop-code-analysis-with-vs2010-ultimate)

Answer (score 6):

The Visual Studio Code Analysis *is* FxCop. Back in the day, those were separate entities, but with I think 2010, FxCop was integrated into Visual Studio as "Static Code Analysis".

Comment: Afaik, The vs ca tool was derived from fxcop, just integrated slightly differently, and only updated with vs releases.

Comment: Static code analysis is different. That's called StyleCop. It looks at code formatting and inclusion if XML comments etc - before compiler gets going. Fxcop looks at the compiled assembly and checks for things like uncalled private members... Basically things more to do with semantics.  I think style cop is a bit much for general use. I tend to use fxcop more..

Comment: There are a few differences though, Visual Studio Premium and up contain more rules than FxCop that is included in the corresponding Windows SDK due to the fact that Visual Studio ships with the Phoenix engine, while the stand alone version does not. See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/04/14/data-flow-analysis-rules-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx **NOTE: The Phoenix Code Analysis engine and associated DFA rules do not ship in the standalone FxCop release.**